# Java package encapsulation in a "ports and adapters" approach (Simon Brown chapter in the "clean architecture" book, by Uncle Bob)

Tags: java, architecture, software-design

I found very interesting the chapter written by Simon Brown in the book "clean architecture" by Uncle Bob. However, there is a point that is not totally clear for me.

Several architecures are discussed, and one of them is the "ports and adapters" approach. It is illustrated on an example dealing with book ordering. In this approach, classes are grouped into 3 packages representing the controller, the use case and the database.

More precisely, the class diagram is the following: OrdersController class (web package) uses the interface OrdersService (domain package). This interface is implmented by the OrdersServiceImpl (domain package), which uses the Orders interface (domain package). The Orders interface is implemented by the JdbcOrdersREpository class in the database package.

To avoid "bad" dependencies, only specific classes are public in those packages. As a result, the database package only has one class (JdbcOrdersREpository) which is not public (figure 34.8 for those who have the book).

How is it possible ? If the JdbcOrdersRepository class is not public, it means it cannot be used outside the package. However, if my understanding of the book is good, it should be used somewhere in the Main component.

Thank you for your help.

I tried to look at Java access modifiers for classes. I was expecting to find a way to use protected/private class outside a package (for exmaple in a Main method).

Comment: "Again, the implementation classes can be made package protected and dependency injected at runtime."